# Printing an Array and index

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am creating a method to be able to call later in my program and want the output to print the index number plus the output based on user input from a scanner.
Ex: if user enters in 10

Comment: What is wrong with the current output?

Comment: I want the output to print the index as well ex: index 1 input is 10, index 2 input is 20 etc

Comment: Use a StringBuilder and use `index` and array value to build your string or String.format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only storing the values in your array into your string, when you're wanting to store the index location and value.  You should also know that array indexes are zero based, meaning that the 1st element is at index 0 and not index 1.  Since you want your output to say `"index 1 input is 10"` you're going to have to add 1 to the index value at the time of storage, but what will be displayed will be inaccurate since 10 is at index 0, 20 is at index 1, etc...

I would also recommend using a `StringBuilder` to build your result, rather than using just a `String`

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(printMiles(new int[] { 10, 20, 30 }));
    }

    public static String printMiles(int[] allMiles) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < allMiles.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("Index %d intput is %d\r\n", i + 1, allMiles[i]));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Index 1 intput is 10
Index 2 intput is 20
Index 3 intput is 30
```

Comment: @SPJava You're welcome...  Kindly check my answer so your question is marked resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `str +=allMiles[index]+ " ";`with

```
str += String.format("index %d input is %d ", index, allMiles[index]);
```